# onkeyup event asp.net

Tags: c#, asp.net, onkeyup

Hi how can i register and call a server side event for onkeyup event in asp.net textbox.

Is it possible?

thank you

Comment: It's possible but why you want to used it.

Comment: I'd suggest doing the keyup event in JavaScript (on the client) and making an AJAX call to the server side. I'd also be very careful because the keyup event has the potential to be called multiple times (that is a lot of times) and your server side processing needs to be really performant in order to be able to pull this off.

Comment: Hi thank you for ur response. Can you give me a simple example

Answer (score 5):

TextBox Web control doesn't provide onkeyXXX events instead subscribe to OnTextChanged event;

```
<asp:TextBox ID='Textbox1' runat='server' OnTextChanged='HandleTextbox1OnTextChanged'>
    </asp:TextBox>

public void HandleTextbox1OnTextChanged(Object sender, EventArgs e)
    {

    }
```

But you can provide onkeyXXX behavior from client-side.

You can add client-side handler like :

```
Textbox1.Attributes.Add("onkeyup", String.Format("onKeyUp({0})", TextBox1.ID));
```

And in the page

```
`<script language='javascript' type='text/javascript'>
   function onKeyUp(id) { //do something; } 
</script>`
```

Also you could use **PageMethods** to make a call to server-side web methods (static methods) from javascript functions.

This [link](http://www.codedigest.com/CodeDigest/80-Calling-a-Serverside-Method-from-JavaScript-in-ASP-Net-AJAX---PageMethods.aspx) might help.

Comment: but this is javascript function right? I want to call server side event.

Comment: If only using the ontextchanged event without the onKeyUp you may need to add the AutoPostBack="true" attribute to the markup